# showing hbase data in JSP taking several minutes.Please advice

Tags: hadoop

I am accessing HBase data from JSP using Hive queries.Now since Hbase can store huge data like  Terabytes of data.If the data is in so much the hive query (which converts into map reduce tasks) will take several minutes of time.So will the JSP page wait say 10 minutes to display the data.What should be the strategy.Is this the correct approach.If not so what is the best approach to show huge hbase data on JSP.

Comment: You're not going to be able to feed terabytes of data into any front-end. You need to use map-reduce to process your data first, then fetch just to one (or very small number) of row(s) from hbase->jsp that answer your exact question. Just because hbase can handle huge datasets it doesn't mean JSP can.

Answer (score 2):

Hive/Any hadoop map-reduce system for that matter, is designed for offline batch processing.  Submitting Hive queries from JSP and waiting for an arbitrary amount of time for data to be ready and be shown on the front-end is a definite no-no. If the cluster is super-busy , your jobs might not be even scheduled within the specified time.

What exactly do you want to show from Hbase on the front end ?

1. If it is a set of rows from a table and you know what the rows are (meaning you have the row key or your application can compute it at run time) , just fetch those rows from and display.
2. if you have to do some SQL-like operations(joins/ selects etc), then I guess you do realize , HBase is a No-SQL system and you are supposed to do these operations in the application and then fetch the appropriate rows using the row key.

For eg: If you have 2 HBase tables , say  Dept (dept Id as row key and a string column(employees) with commma separated list of empIds) and Employee( emp Id as row key and columns Name, Age, Salary) . To find the employee with highest salary in a dept, you have to

a.Fetch the row from the Dept table (using dept Id)

b. Iterate the list of empIds from the employees column.

c. In each iteration , fetch the row from Employee table(by empId row key)

and find the max

Yes HBase can handle TBs of data, but you ll almost never have to show that much of data on the front-end using JSP. Im guessing, you ll most likely be interested in only a portion of the data , though the backing HBase table is much bigger

Comment: thanks all.but even if jsp is fetching 1 row in 1 million rows it will still search those many data and take huge time to process thro hive?

Comment: fetching 1 row know which row you want to fetch (knowing the row key) is a very quick operation. But if you want to select a row based on a SQL like condition, yes , it is going to run a massive M/R job on the cluster.  So yes, if you doing M/R , you should be planning to show the results from a JSP.